# How to pass dynamic value in phpmailer function in php

Tags: php, email, attachment

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <noreply@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: admin@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->isHTML(true);
$email->From      = '<noreply@gmail.com>';
$email->FromName  = 'Name';
$email->Subject   = $Subject; //subject name 
$email->Body      = $txt; //This is html message
$email->AddAddress($to);
$email->AddAttachment( "http://www.domain.in/" , "invoice.pdf", 'base64', 'application/octet-stream' );
$email->Send();
```

File is not sending and if I'm passing variable as parameter in above part it is not working while in static value it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing an `url` **not** a `path` to a file as argument.

You may want to use something like:

```
$email->AddAttachment( "/path/to/invoice.pdf" , "invoice.pdf", 'base64', 'application/octet-stream' );
```

> The command to attach a local file is simply
>   `$mail->addAttachment($path);`, where `$path` contains the path to the
>   file you want to send, and can be placed anywhere between `$mail = new
>   PHPMailer;` and sending the message. Note that you cannot use a URL
>   for the path - you may only use **local filesystem** `path`. See notes
>   on string attachments below for how to use remote content.

---

You can also use `addStringAttachment`:

```
$url = "http://www.domain.in/"
$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents($url), 'myfile.pdf');
```

> The `addStringAttachment()` method works just like `addAttachment()`,
>   but you pass the actual contents of the item instead of a file system
>   `path`. The `$filename` parameter is required as it's used to provide
>   a filename for the string data at the receiver end.

---

[Read the documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial)

Comment: I tried this one also. see below code also it is showing an error "could not access file: " @Pedro Lobito

Answer (score 0):

It is working now

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
        $body = $txt;

            $mail->AddReplyTo("X@gmail.com","Test Lernt");
            $mail->SetFrom('noreply@X.in', 'xxxx');


            $mail->AddAddress($to, "Giridhari Lal");       
            $mail->Subject    = $subject;       
            $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

            $mail->MsgHTML($body);
            //documentation for Output method here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm  
            $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output($filename,'F');     
            $path = "invoice.pdf";

            $mail->AddAttachment($path, '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
            var_dump($mail);
            $mail->send();
```

Comment: @Pedro Lobito see this code. still file is not sending except html content